# How to cut the heatmap horizontally at a designated row position?

Tags: r

I have the following heatmap:

```
test <- data.frame(revenue=c(34, 10, 0.40, 49, 43, 55, 99),
                   expenses=c(22, 0.26, 31, 40, 20, 25, 22),
                   profit=c(12, 10, 0.14, 0.9, 0.8, 15, 16))

rownames(test) <- c("Gene1",
                    "Gene2",
                    "Gene3",
                    "Gene4",
                    "Gene5",
                    "Gene6",
                    "Gene7")    
test
col_palette <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("green", "white", "red"))(30)
pheatmap(test, 
         cutree_rows = 1, 
         color = col_palette,
         scale = "none",
         cluster_cols = F,
         cluster_rows=F)
```

and I just want to cut it horizontally so the final picture would look something like this:

[image]

I don't need cutting by clustering or whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily,  `pheatmap` has an argument to do exactly that: `gaps_row`.   Try

```
pheatmap(test, 
         cutree_rows = 1, 
         color = col_palette,
         scale = "none",
         cluster_cols = F,
         cluster_rows=F,
         gaps_row=c(2,5))
```